# Como criar um executável para um programa python que instala as bibliotecas usadas?

Tags: python

Olá, tenho um código q fiz em python e que usa algumas bibliotecas. Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer um executável para esse programa e q o usuário q usa-lo n precise ter o python nem essas bibliotecas instaladas.

Comment: Especifique melhor o seu problema para que os usuários possam te ajudar. Se pude colocar o código do que você tentou até agora é melhor ainda.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Parece que você quer `compilar` o seu código fonte em um executável.

---

Se o seu código tiver sido escrito para `python 2.x ou 3.0-3.1`, você pode utilizar, por exemplo, a biblioteca [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Para criar o executável, você deve:

1. instalar o `py2exe` (`pip install py2exe`)
2. ter o código a ser compilado salvo no computador (por exemplo o código `hello.py`)
3. criar um arquivo chamado `setup.py` na mesma pasta do código a ser compilado, com o seguinte conteúdo:

   ```
   from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe

   setup(console=['hello.py'])
   ```
4. Navegar pelo terminal até a pasta com os arquivos (`hello.py` e `setup.py`) e rodar o comando `python setup.py install`
5. Pronto. Na pasta deverão ter sido criadas 2 novas pastas. Em uma delas você encontrará o seu `.exe`.

OBS:

- *1) Pode ver na documentação [mais parâmetros](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) para adicionar na hora de compilar*;
- *2) Se o seu código tiver sido escrito para `Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.0 ou 3.1`, você deve se atentar ao fato de que o `py2exe` não inclui automaticamente a `DLL` `MSVCR90.dll` na pasta `dist`, sendo assim, você deve colocá-la lá manualmente.*

---

Se o seu código tiver sido escrito para `python 2.7 ou 3.3—3.5`, você pode utilizar, por exemplo, a biblioteca [`PyInstaller`](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Para criar o executável, você deve:

1. Instalar o pacote `pyinstaller` (`pip install pyinstaller`)
2. Para criar o .exe, navegue pelo terminal até a pasta com o código a ser compilado e digite:

   ```
   pyinstaller --onefile script.py
   ```
3. Pronto.

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode utilizar o [cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) para "empacotar" o seu programa e gerar um executável.

Eu e um amigo criamos a um tempo atrás uma versão gráfica para o compilador utilizando a biblioteca `Tkinter`, que você pode achar no [meu Github](https://github.com/lariodiniz/CX_Compilar).